# How to notch container with radius from center

Tags: flutter, dart, containers, radius

I want to implement this widget with this curved notch but I can't cut the container from center with border radius like the picture below .

this is my target widget

[image]

and this in my code

```
BottomAppBar(
      shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
      child: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .07,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            end: Alignment.centerRight,
            begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
            colors: [
              blueColor,
              lightColor,
            ],
          ),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Image.asset(
                "assets/images/home.png",
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .035,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .3,
              ),
              Spacer(),
              Image.asset(
                "assets/images/cart.png",
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .035,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .3,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Edit : in which way can use custom painter to achieve this case !

Comment: Try this package. https://pub.dev/packages/animated_bottom_navigation_bar It seems quite customizable. If you need more control over the design however, you will have to write a custom clipper for the bottom bar.

Comment: With current configuration, use clipBehaviour: Clip.antiAlias, in bottom app bar. This will cut a notch where the floating button is docked. This notch is circular however.

Comment: @AfridiKayal it is great package but i can't make background color gradient

Comment: the next solution great for me thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your place I would make an image with that design but without the icons, you add the icons later with a Stack, so I solve complex designs.
It is not a bad idea...

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom clipper. (Look for Custom clipper tutorial on YouTube)

Comment: I was search but can't get anything help ... thanks for you